# Study of node expansion and O(n) for maze

Tags: python

My code itself doesn't have an issue, this is more of a general question about code that already works. I solve a maze using breadth first search and I'm looking to study the node expansion, space complexity, and O(n) - which, for BFS, is O(b^d).

I'm not used to studying the program once finished and I was wondering if there are any specific methods that are best. I know the code itself will give me a time but I was wondering if there are any library functions that could help, or if there is maybe a function I could implement that would better show me quantitative results.

I have the ability to run the test on multiple different mazes (I even have a maze creator) but I'm asking for something (anything) more quantitative than just running this code on three or four different mazes and using the auto-output. I'm also using pycharm, which I'm unfamiliar with - are there ways the IDE can formalize this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maze problem (without any assumption and knowledge of the network learnt prior), A-STAR algorithm is the state of the earth. Its complexities are:

Worst complexity: O(|E|) = O(b^d)
Space complexity: O(|V|) = O(b^d)

For fairly large network (such as road networks), practical algorithms exists because we can pre-compute some paths apriori. They will have less time complexity (trade-off with larger space complexity) after the pre-processing (or learning) has been done.

Comment: If you like to get data, generate yourself by generating a couple mazes and running random points and collect complexity. 

Usually, algorithms are proven mathematically not using data (data-driven proof is known as empirical evidence). If you access the original paper, you will see the mathematical proof.